# Problem when generating grub.cfg

Tags: 12.04, grub2, bootloader

When I ran `update-grub` in terminal it gave me this message:

```
root@ThinkPad-W520:/dev# sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
grep: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/swaps: No such file or directory
Found Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda3
done
```

Do you know why is this happening?I am referring to these two lines which begin with `grep`
I have never seen these again.

Here is also the output that `fdisk -l` gave:

```
 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   671326207   335662080   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       671328254   703326207    15998977    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   *   703326208   704043007      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       704043008   937699327   116828160    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       671328256   703326207    15998976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there doesn't seem to be a problem as the command finishes without error. However, you ought to have `/proc/mounts` and `/proc/swaps`. Maybe your /proc didn't get mounted or got unmounted.

Check that your /etc/fstab has a line `proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0`. Then try `sudo mount /proc` and see if the files are back.